# Ember yield param passing

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to pass an argument to a yield block, however I missing something that I don't see. Here is the case:

**components/table-notes.hbs**

```
<table>
   ...
  <tbody>
    {{#each note in notes}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{yield note}}</td>
        ...
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

**elsewhere**

```
{{#table-notes notes=model.notes}}
  //do something with each note
{{/table-notes}}
```

Is it anything wrong or incomplete with this param passing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you throw this up into jsbin, pls?

Comment: also, which version of Ember.js are you using?

Comment: The latest version. And nope, I'm sorry, I think that's pretty straight what I'm asking. I don't think that a jsbin can change anything.

Comment: you can use `{{note}}` in the "elsewhere" block

Comment: 1.9? 1.10? Latest means different thing to different ppl :)

Comment: @Kalman I'm using 1.8.1, it wasn't even the latest.

Comment: @Grapho it isn't working for me, it throws me this error "TypeError: options.data is undefined"

Comment: Is there any way to do this in ember 2.x?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in a version prior to 1.10. In 1.10 though, you **can** do the following:

Declare the component template and `yield`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/table-notes">
   {{#each notes as |note|}}
    {{ yield note }}
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

And also declare in the template **using** the component that the variable is called `note` as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">    
  {{#table-notes notes=model.notes as |note|}}
    <h3>{{ note }}</h3>
  {{/table-notes}}
</script>
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wijidu/1/edit?html,output)

You can read more about block params in components, a new feature in 1.10, [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/12/08/ember-1-9-0-released.html#toc_block-params).