# Accessing the current model within a yield

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm looking for how to access the current model with-in an each from a yield statement. Any ideas?

**Model**

```
models: [{
   id: 1,
   name:'Red',
   value: '#ff0000'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name:'Yellow',
  value: '#ffff00'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name:'Blue',
  value: '#0000ff'
}];
```

**Template**

```
{{#table-list models=models config=colorModelTableListConfig}}
  {{model.id}}
  {{model.name}}
  {{model.value}}
{{/table-list}}
```

**Component** (table-list)

```
<!-- Searching markup-->
<table>
  {{#each th in config.tableHeaders}}
    <th>{{th}}</th>
  {{/each}}

  {{#each model in models}}
    {{yield}}
  {{/each}}
</table>
<!-- Pagination markup-->
```

**Side-note** I can't throw the each inside the yield, this will cause issues with my searching, pagination and other functionality

**Answer**

[Ember yield param passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989968/ember-yield-param-passing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters to the yield block:

```
{{yield model}}
```

If necessary you can adjust for a different name:

```
{{#with model as foobar}}
  {{yield foobar}}
{{/with}}
```

You can do something similar using the each helper:

```
{{#each model in models as |foobar|}}
  {{yield foobar}}
{{/each}}
```

More examples: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/06e41ad7ccd28558dd4e651aa070bc06f7757821/packages/ember-htmlbars/tests/integration/block_params_test.js

Comment: I've tried `{{yield model}}` and `{{yield model=model}}` when I'm inside the table list component, I'm not able to access `model.name`